# Angular 5 tokenGetter method in JWT Module doens't set token

Tags: angular, jwt

I have a application in Angular that use JWT for authentication. When a application is loaded for first time, everything works, every request has Authorization header included with token, but when I press f5 key for update in login, all requests are make without token. So after that I receive 403 status code.

**Method in LoginService**

```
login(login, senha) {
return this.http.post(this.utilService.urlName + 'login', JSON.stringify({ login: login, senha: senha }), { observe: 'response' })
  .map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      let token = response.headers.get("Authorization");
      localStorage.setItem('auth_token', token);
      this.loggedIn = true;
    }
    return response.ok;
  });
}
```

**Token getter method**

```
export function tokenGetter() {
return localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
}
```

**My module**

```
 JwtModule.forRoot({
        config:{
            tokenGetter:tokenGetter,
            whitelistedDomains: [getUrlServer()],
            blacklistedRoutes: [getUrlServer()+'/login']            }
    }),
```

Comment: Check this out. This may help. https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/464